# Change the value of a cell as in excel?

Tags: r, excel, spotfire

I'm working on Spotfire and I would like to know if it possible in R to change a cell value in a data frame like in excel?

For example, clicking the cell and entering the new value?

Comment: check the `?edit` function

Comment: thanks, I will try it on Spotfire

Answer (score 1):

Actually by clicking, there is no way as far as I know. These are options in spreadsheets like excel...

But you can change for example the Element in the second row and 5th column by using

```
my_data_frame[2,5] <- 'new value'
```